# Find all subsequences with specific length in sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r, sequence

I want to find all subsequences within a sequence with (minimum) length of n. Lets assume I have this sequence

```r
sequence <- c(1,2,3,2,5,3,2,6,7,9)
```

and I want to find the increasing subsequences with minimum length of 3. The ouput should be a dataframe with start and end position for each subsequence found.

```r
df =data.frame(c(1,7),c(3,10))
colnames(df) <- c("start", "end")
```

Can somebody give a hint how to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using only base R

```
n <- 3

do.call(rbind, sapply(split(1:length(sequence), cumsum(c(0, diff(sequence)) < 1)), 
        function(x) if (length(x) >= n) c(start = x[1], end = x[length(x)])))

#  start end
#1    1    3
#4    7   10
```

`split` the index of `sequence` based on the continuous incremental subsequences, if the `length` of each group is greater than equal to `n` return the start and end index of that group.

---

To understand lets break this down and understand it step by step

Using `diff` we can find difference between consecutive elements

```
diff(sequence)
#[1]  0  1  1 -1  3 -2 -1  4  1  2
```

We check which of them do not have increasing subsequences

```
diff(sequence) < 1
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

and take cumulative sum over them to create groups

```
cumsum(c(0, diff(sequence)) < 1)
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4
```

Based on this groups, we `split` the index from `1:length(sequence)`

```
split(1:length(sequence), cumsum(c(0, diff(sequence)) < 1))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`2`
#[1] 4 5

#$`3`
#[1] 6

#$`4`
#[1]  7  8  9 10
```

Using `sapply` we loop over this list and return the start and end index of the list `if` the `length` of the list is `>=` `n` (3 in this case)

```
sapply(split(1:length(sequence), cumsum(c(0, diff(sequence)) < 1)), 
       function(x) if (length(x) >= n) c(start = x[1], end = x[length(x)]))

#$`1`
#start   end 
#    1     3 

#$`2`
# NULL

#$`3`
#NULL

#$`4`
#start   end 
#    7    10
```

Finally, `rbind` all of them together using `do.call`. `NULL` elements are automatically ignored.

```
do.call(rbind, sapply(split(1:length(sequence), cumsum(c(0, diff(sequence)) < 1)), 
       function(x) if (length(x) >= n) c(start = x[1], end = x[length(x)])))

#  start end
#1     1   3
#4     7  10
```

Comment: Great answer, but a little difficult to understand. Would you please tell me how to get the decreasing subsequences? I was not able to modify your code for decreasing subsequences.

Comment: @MatthiasHab1986  I have added some explanation for the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using base R. I tried to comment it well but it may still be hard to follow. It seems like you wanted direction / to learn, more than an outright answer so definitely follow up with questions if anything is unclear (or doesn't work for your actual application).

Also, for your data, I added a 12 on the end to make sure it was returning the correct position for repeated increases greater than `n` (3 in this case):

```
# Data (I added 11 on the end)
sequence <- c(1,2,3,2,5,3,2,6,7,9, 12)

# Create indices for whether or not the numbers in the sequence increased
indices <- c(1, diff(sequence) >= 1)
indices
[1] 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Now that we have the indices, we need to get the start and end postions for repeates >= 3

```
# Finding increasing sequences of n length using rle
n <- 3
n <- n - 1

# Examples 
rle(indices)$lengths
[1] 3 1 1 2 4

rle(indices)$values
[1] 1 0 1 0 1

# Finding repeated TRUE (1) in our indices vector
reps <- rle(indices)$lengths >= n & rle(indices)$values == 1
reps
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# Creating a vector of positions for the end of a sequence
# Because our indices are true false, we can use cumsum along
# with rle to create the positions of the end of the sequences
rle_positions <- cumsum(rle(indices)$lengths)
rle_positions
[1]  3  4  5  7 11

# Creating start sequence vector and subsetting start / end using reps
start <- c(1, head(rle_positions, -1))[reps]

end <- rle_positions[reps]

data.frame(start, end)
  start end
1     1   3
2     7  11
```

Or, concisely:

```
n <- 3
n <- n-1
indices <- c(1, diff(sequence) >= 1)
reps <- rle(indices)$lengths >= n & rle(indices)$values == 1
rle_positions <- cumsum(rle(indices)$lengths)
data.frame(start = c(1, head(rle_positions, -1))[reps], 
           end = rle_positions[reps])
  start end
1     1   3
2     7  11
```

EDIT: @Ronak's update made me realize I should be using `diff` instead of `sapply` with an anonymous function for my first step. Updated the answer b/c it was not catching an increase at the end of the vector (e.g., `sequence <- c(1,2,3,2,5,3,2,6,7,9,12, 11, 11, 20, 100)`, also needed to add one more line under `n <- 3`. This should work as intended now.

Comment: Thanks for this great explanation. I tried your code for the expanded sequence 
`sequence <- c(1,2,3,2,5,3,2,6,7,9, 12,11,10,9)`
with the result, that the decreasing subsequence at the end is matching too (from 11 to 14). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Great catch! So, if you add this to the `reps`  line it will fix it: `& rle(indices)$values == 1`. I was accidentally matching repeated 0's (FALSES) as well as 1(TRUES) when I only wanted TRUE. I updated the answer as well.